# sys.argv : index out of range

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pycharm, sys

I try to run this code

```
import sys
import numpy as np
filename = sys.argv[1]
X = []
y = []
with open(filename, 'r') as f: 
     for line in f.readlines():
        xt, yt = [float(i) for i in line.split(',')]
        X.append(xt)
        y.append(yt)
```

and I get this error

```
4 filename = sys.argv[1]   
  5 X = []   
  6 y = []  
IndexError: list index out of range
```

how can I fix it ?

I have a file in txt that I want to read my data from it.

```
4.94,4.37
-1.58,1.7
-4.45,1.88
-6.06,0.56
-1.22,2.23
-3.55,1.53
0.36,2.99
-3.24,0.48
1.31,2.76
2.17,3.99
2.94,3.25
-0.92,2.27
-0.91,2.0
1.24,4.75
1.56,3.52
-4.14,1.39
3.75,4.9
4.15,4.44
0.33,2.72
3.41,4.59
2.27,5.3
2.6,3.43
1.06,2.53
1.04,3.69
2.74,3.1
-0.71,2.72
-2.75,2.82
0.55,3.53
-3.45,1.77
1.09,4.61
2.47,4.24
-6.35,1.0
1.83,3.84
-0.68,2.42
-3.83,0.67
-2.03,1.07
3.13,3.19
0.92,4.21
4.02,5.24
3.89,3.94
-1.81,2.85
3.94,4.86
-2.0,1.31
0.54,3.99
0.78,2.92
2.15,4.72
2.55,3.83
-0.63,2.58
1.06,2.89
-0.36,1.99
```

Comment: Are you supplying a `filename` when calling the script?  e.g. `python prog.py myfile.txt`

Comment: no?? how can I do this in pycharm?

Comment: Using `pycharm` is significant.  What I recommended applies to calling it from a command line shell.  How are you invoking this script from `pycharm`?  Isn't there a way of adding arguments to that invocation?

Comment: Oh. Now I see the problem. In PyCharm you could pass the filename in the Run Configuration -> Script Parameters. Have a look at the Video 3 here: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/documentation/

Comment: thanks!! @s.meissner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you pass the *filename* as @hpaulj suggested. You could also check the length of sys.argv

```
import sys
print(sys.argv, len(sys.argv))
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
   sys.exit('Usage: %s input_file' % sys.argv[0])
```

You may also want to check this helper class:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput